# Determine the posterior density of $θ$ after doing $n$ coin tosses

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I am given a that I toss a coin and the prior  $θ \stackrel{}{\sim} Uniform[0.4, 0.6]$

$\textbf{Note:}$ $\theta$ is the probability of getting a head on a single toss

If I toss the coin $n$ times and obtain $n$ heads, then what is the posterior density
of $θ$?

Comment: Can you apply Bayes' theorem?

Comment: Yeah but I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

Let's do this for one toss of the coin. Suppose that we toss this coin once to get the roll $X$ and it falls heads  (i.e. $X=H$).

Note that the probability of getting the head depends on the value of $\theta$, so
$$
\mathbb{P}[X=H]
 = \int_{0.4}^{0.6} \mathbb{P}[X=H,\theta=t]dt
 = \int_{0.4}^{0.6} \mathbb{P}[X=H|\theta=t] f_\theta(t) dt
 = \int_{0.4}^{0.6} \frac{t\ dt}{0.2} dt
 = 0.5,
$$
which intuitively makes a lot of sense since the uniform distribution is symmetric around $0.5$...

The new distribution would be given by
$$
f_\theta(t|X=H)
 = \frac{\mathbb{P}[X=H|\theta=t]}{\mathbb{P}[X=H]}
 = \ldots
$$

can you complete this and then generalize to $n$ rolls?

You can try reading up on [Bayes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference), especially in the section [Making a prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_inference#Making_a_prediction).

Comment: Can you give a hint? I still can't fully get it

Comment: @VirgOpta please be very specific. What are you having problems with exactly? Did you try to compute $f_\theta(t|X=H)$? Can you evaluate the denominator? The numerator?